# Finding outliers or noise using birch

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-computing, outliers

dbscan (as in python , sklearn) has a natural way of finding outliers. The noise points are given cluster id -1. Similarly is there a way to find noise using Birch? 
My code is shown below.  (Python 3.5.2)

```
import numpy as np
X = np.loadtxt("i.txt",dtype=float)
birch_model = Birch(threshold=7.0, n_clusters=None)
birch_model.fit(X)
result = birch_model.predict(X)
```

Comment: Simply, Birch does not have this functionality. You may use DBSCAN to find the noisy points and remove them.

Comment: Yes, but what is/are some of the criteria to select noise clusters? I can think of max number of points in a cluster, say N. If a cluster has less than N points, I can classify it as noise. But this seems very arbitrary.

Comment: DBSCAN will tell you the noisy points and you can remove them from your dataset, after that you can apply Birch to the refined dataset. For details of how DBSCAN finds noisy points, you may read the asdociated paper which is aldo mentioned in scikit's documentation. Does that help?

Comment: Any solution to this question?..I have a similar case, predicting noisy points with Birch